# Android AlertDialog custom view text color

Tags: android, styles, textview, android-alertdialog

I want to make my AlertDialog TextView color (custom view) to depend on Android version.
On Android 2.x AlertDialog has a dark background, at Android 4.0 there is a light background. So the text color has to be white or black.
How to refer a style or theme that make that for me automatically?

Here my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.remotedialog, null);
alert.setView(view);
```

Here my custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewremoteusername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="???"
        android:text="@string/remoteusernametitle" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittextremoteusername"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have a `style` entry in `values-v14/styles` as (blind coding):

```
<style name="MyTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</>
</style>
```

while in `values/styles`:

```
<style name="MyTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</>
</style>
```

and in refer to this from your layout:

```
style="@style/MyTextStyle"
```

In this way for pre-v14 devices the text color will be black (you can customize the colors), while for post-v14 included, the text color will be white.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but isn't there a global style that defines the "AlertDialog text color" that I can use, e.g. style="@android:style/AlertDialogTextStyle"?

Comment: None that I have noticed ... If it would exist, I guess its existence would base on above mechanism.

Comment: But are you sure, that all AlertDialog's from SDK 14 have a white background?

Comment: I am not that sure. The API looks to have light background, but I don't guarantee some model from an Asian manufacturer will not obey this rule ... For this reason, you should override as many as possible from your style properties.

Comment: @almisoft: Did my answer and comments help so far? :)

Comment: Yes, but I am still looking for a better solution. It must be possible to determine the current color of the dialog text...

Comment: `It must be possible to determine the current color of the dialog text` ... I thought you want to set it, not to find it

Answer (score 0):

I think, that is the best solution, it is working for me with all Android versions, Holo & Holo Light Themes:

res/values/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="dialog_text_appearance">
        <attr name="alert_dialog_text_appearance" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppThemeABS" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="alert_dialog_text_appearance">@style/AlertDialogTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeABSLight" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="alert_dialog_text_appearance">@style/AlertDialogTextAppearanceLight</item>
    </style>

    <color name="Black">#000000</color>
    <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="AlertDialogTextColor">#c8c8c8</color>

    <style name="AlertDialogTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/AlertDialogTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTextAppearanceLight">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/AlertDialogTextColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AlertDialogTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTextAppearanceLight">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/layout/remotedialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewremoteusername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?attr/alert_dialog_text_appearance"
        android:text="@string/remoteusernametitle" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittextremoteusername"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```